# SQL Conversion Error on Inner Join Statement - Not Converting Anything

Tags: sql

I've used this site for research for years but can't figure this one out from my research.  Getting the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '38221.0' to data type int.

This '38221.0' correlates to the 'CP.DNCP_PATIENTID' from the below code:

```
SELECT  PAT.V51_PRSNPERSONNUMBER AS PSNNMBR,
PAT.V51_PRSNFIRSTNAME AS FIRSTNAME,
PAT.V51_PRSNMIDDLENAME AS MIDDLENAME,
PAT.V51_PRSNLASTNAME AS LASTNAME,
ADDR.V8_PERSONHOMEADDRLINE1 AS ADDRESS,
ADDR.V8_PERSONHOMEADDRLINE2 AS ADDRESS2,
ADDR.V8_PERSONHOMEADDRCITY AS CITY,
ADDR.V8_PERSONHOMEADDRSTATE AS STATE,
ADDR.V8_PERSONHOMEADDRZIP AS ZIP,
PAT.V51_PRSNDOB AS DOB,
PAT.V51_PRSNSEX AS SEX,
PAT.V51_PRSNSSN AS SSN,
ADDR.V8_PERSONHOMEPHONENUMBER AS HOMEPHONE,
ADDR.V8_PERSONMOBILEPHONENUMBER AS MOBILEPHONE, 
CV.V9_DNPLANSORTNAME AS INSPLAN,
CV.V9_DNCARRIERNAME AS INSCARRIER,
COORD.PCCUSERNAME AS CARECOORDINATOR
FROM I_DNCHGSPMTS CP
LEFT OUTER JOIN IPROCEDURE PR
    ON (CP.DNCP_PROCEDURECODE = PR.PRPROCEDURECODE AND CP.OFFICE_ID = PR.OFFICE_ID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VSTAFFCHGBILL STFBILL
    ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = STFBILL.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_PRACTICEID = STFBILL.V69_STPRACTICEID AND
        CP.DNCP_STAFFID_CREDITED = STFBILL.V69_STSTAFFID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VPROVCHGBILL BILL
    ON (STFBILL.V69_STSTAFFID = BILL.V58_PROVPROVIDERID AND STFBILL.OFFICE_ID = BILL.OFFICE_ID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN I_DNCHGCOVERAGE CHGCV
    ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = CHGCV.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_CHARGESID = CHGCV.TPSCHARGESID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VDNPLANCHGCV1 CV
    ON (CHGCV.CHGCVR1PLANID = CV.V9_DNPLANID AND CHGCV.OFFICE_ID = CV.OFFICE_ID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VDEPTCHG DEP
    ON (CP.DNCP_DEPARTMENTCODE = DEP.V4_DPTDEPARTMENTCODE AND CP.OFFICE_ID = DEP.OFFICE_ID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VDNADDRSPAT ADDR
    ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = ADDR.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_PATIENTID = ADDR.V8_TPSPERSONID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VPERSONPAT PAT
    ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = PAT.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_PATIENTID = PAT.V51_PRSNPERSONID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN IACCOUNT ACC
    ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = ACC.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_ACCOUNTSID = ACC.ACCACCOUNTSID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN IPAYMENT PMT
    ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = PMT.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_PAYMENTSID = PMT.PMTPAYMENTSID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VLUPROCCLASS CL
    ON (PR.OFFICE_ID = CL.OFFICE_ID AND PR.PRCLASS = CL.V85_LUCLOOKUPCODE)
LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VSVCCNTRPROC SVC
    ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = SVC.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_SERVICECENTERID = SVC.V75_SVCSERVICECENTERID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN I_DNDXPROCEVENT DX
    ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = DX.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_PROCEDUREEVENTSID = DX.TPSPROCEDUREEVENTSID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN IPATIENT IPAT
    ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = IPAT.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_PATIENTID = IPAT.PATDNPERSONNUMBER)
LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VPATCARECOORD COORD
    ON (IPAT.OFFICE_ID = COORD.OFFICE_ID AND IPAT.PATCARECOORDINATORID = COORD.PCCMMUSERSID)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  CP.DNCP_PATIENTID AS PSNNMBR,
        MAX(CP.DNCP_FROMSERVICEDATE) AS SVCDT
        --MIN(CP.DNCP_AMOUNT_CHARGE) AS CHGAMT
    FROM I_DNCHGSPMTS CP
        LEFT OUTER JOIN IPROCEDURE PR
            ON (CP.DNCP_PROCEDURECODE = PR.PRPROCEDURECODE AND CP.OFFICE_ID = PR.OFFICE_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VSTAFFCHGBILL STFBILL
            ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = STFBILL.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_PRACTICEID = STFBILL.V69_STPRACTICEID AND
            CP.DNCP_STAFFID_CREDITED = STFBILL.V69_STSTAFFID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VPROVCHGBILL BILL
            ON (STFBILL.V69_STSTAFFID = BILL.V58_PROVPROVIDERID AND STFBILL.OFFICE_ID = BILL.OFFICE_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_DNCHGCOVERAGE CHGCV
            ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = CHGCV.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_CHARGESID = CHGCV.TPSCHARGESID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VDNPLANCHGCV1 CV
            ON (CHGCV.CHGCVR1PLANID = CV.V9_DNPLANID AND CHGCV.OFFICE_ID = CV.OFFICE_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VDEPTCHG DEP
            ON (CP.DNCP_DEPARTMENTCODE = DEP.V4_DPTDEPARTMENTCODE AND CP.OFFICE_ID = DEP.OFFICE_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VDNADDRSPAT ADDR
            ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = ADDR.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_PATIENTID = ADDR.V8_TPSPERSONID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VPERSONPAT PAT
            ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = PAT.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_PATIENTID = PAT.V51_PRSNPERSONID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN IACCOUNT ACC
            ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = ACC.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_ACCOUNTSID = ACC.ACCACCOUNTSID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN IPAYMENT PMT
            ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = PMT.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_PAYMENTSID = PMT.PMTPAYMENTSID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VLUPROCCLASS CL
            ON (PR.OFFICE_ID = CL.OFFICE_ID AND PR.PRCLASS = CL.V85_LUCLOOKUPCODE)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VSVCCNTRPROC SVC
            ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = SVC.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_SERVICECENTERID = SVC.V75_SVCSERVICECENTERID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_DNDXPROCEVENT DX
            ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = DX.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_PROCEDUREEVENTSID = DX.TPSPROCEDUREEVENTSID)
    WHERE CP.OFFICE_ID = 'EDQV'
        AND CP.DNCP_ACTIVITYTYPE = 'CHG'
        AND (CP.DNCP_PROCEDURECODE LIKE '99490' OR CP.DNCP_PROCEDURECODE LIKE 'CCM')
        AND (DATEDIFF(DAY,CP.DNCP_POSTDATE,GETDATE())) < 180
    GROUP BY CP.DNCP_PATIENTID
    ) AS MAXSVCDATE
    ON (CP.DNCP_PATIENTID = MAXSVCDATE.PSNNMBR AND CP.DNCP_FROMSERVICEDATE = MAXSVCDATE.SVCDT) --AND CP.DNCP_AMOUNT_CHARGE = MAXSVCDATE.CHGAMT)
WHERE CP.OFFICE_ID = 'EDQV'
```

As I'm not converting anything, I'm unsure why I'm getting this error.  I've used a variation of this coding on many projects and never received the error.  I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: You are comparing a char or varchar field to an int field. This will implicitly convert the varchar to int before performing the comparison.

Comment: The error message tells me that...I'm looking for where the error is.

Comment: @Ben, why not as answer? :-)

Comment: Perhaps I was misled by your statement that you were not sure why you were getting the error? Nevertheless, we cannot know what the types of your fields are, but it is probably one you join to either `PSNNMBR` or `DNCP_PATIENTID`.

Comment: You may not be converting anything, but the engine is attempting an implicit cast and failing.  it appears `CP.DNCP_PATIENTID` when evaluated against ADDR.V8_TPSPERSONID or PAT.V51_PRSNPERSONID is failing on the typecast.

Comment: @Ben yes, what Ben said.

Comment: Ok, I'll start commenting out single section to narrow down the error.  Thank you for your responses.  Probably should have done that first to add more specificity above.  I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I got it.  I was thinking it was in my INNER JOIN but it was in one of the other joins.  I was joining a PERSONNUMBER to a PERSONID.  I fixed it and everything works smoothly now.  A case of staring at it too long and not seeing what's right in front of you.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try `CONV(N,from_base,to_base)`,it converts numbers between different number bases. It returns a string representation of the number N, converted 
from base from_base to  to_base